# FullCalendar change view from month to day

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

In my FullCalendar application, more specifically on the month view visualization, I have a link that appears whenever 3 or more events are added to the same day, then I want to make that link lead to the day view mode for that particular day.

```
$(".events-view-more a").click(function () {
    alert("clicou");
});
```

The parent (parent of .events-view-more a) td element contains a data attribute with the date value containing something like "2013-11-29".

How can I use this to change the visualization mode to day view of that day?

Comment: check [changeView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/) and [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Answer (score 16):

Something like this will take you from the Month view to the Day view if you click anywhere on the cell in the Month view:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

   //other parameters here          

   dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');

   }

});
```

Hopefully this is useful for others, I know it is an old post.

Comment: This works, but you need to flip the order. Change the view then the date, otherwise it puts you back at the default date!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".events-view-more a").click(function () {
    var date=new Date($(this).parents('td').attr('date'));
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For everyone searching for a **non-jquery** solution:

```
window.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(element, options);

// do stuff ...

window.calendar.changeView("timeGridDay")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var ajandamodu=view.name;
    if(ajandamodu=='month')
    {                             
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicDay'  );
    }
},
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and please summerize the problem and the solution, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is how I do it in the app I'm building. Basically this is an event handler for the dayClick event. This event, obviously, occurs when a day is clicked. There's also a weekClick for the week views. The bit below:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicDay'  );

Is actually all you need. The #calendar selector is the container you initially called fullCalendar on, the 'changeView' parameter is the function that's being called and the basicDay parameter is the view, which can be any of the views that fullCalendar provides.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is specifying the view-name in the `header` (e.g. `agendaDay` or `agendaWeek`):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here

    header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'today prev,next agendaDay,agendaWeek'
    },

    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@rodrigoalves Try below one in your calendar configuration.

```
eventLimit: 3,
eventLimitClick: 'day',
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the above here is my solution for angularjs

```
$scope.alertDayClick = function(event) {

    // if on month view go day view
    var view = uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'getView' );

    if (view.type === 'month') {
        console.log(view.type);
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', event );
        return;
    }
}
```

I set up my Cal div like this

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" config="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="myCalendar" data-ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```